# How to submit array as query string using ParseQueryString

Tags: c#, php, arrays

Here is my C# code

```
var UriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://smsgateway.me/api/v3/messages/send/");
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
parameters["email"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:email", NamespaceManager).Value;
parameters["password"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:password", NamespaceManager).Value;
parameters["device"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:device", NamespaceManager).Value; ;
parameters["number"] = "123456789";//any number
parameters["message"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:SMS_TO_BE_SENT", NamespaceManager).Value; ;
UriBuilder.Query = parameters.ToString();
//UriBuilder.Fragment = "some_fragment";

Uri finalUrl = UriBuilder.Uri;
var request = WebRequest.Create(finalUrl);

// Get the response.
WebResponse result = request.GetResponse();
```

And here is sample PHP code

```
<?php
include "smsGateway.php";
$smsGateway = new SmsGateway('demo@smsgateway.me', 'password');

$deviceID = 1;
$numbers = ['+44771232343', '+44771232344'];
$message = 'Hello World!';

$options = [
'send_at' => strtotime('+10 minutes'), // Send the message in 10 minutes
'expires_at' => strtotime('+1 hour') // Cancel the message in 1 hour if the message is not yet sent
];

//Please note options is no required and can be left out
$result = $smsGateway->sendMessageToManyNumbers($number, $message, $deviceID, $options);
?>
```

The number in the PHP example is an array. How can I pass an array in the query string using `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Do you want to implement the PHP example using C#?

Comment: @ venerik Yes. All other things are working fine except Number in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an array of numbers to the query string like this:

```
parameters["number[0]"] = "123456789";
parameters["number[1]"] = "987654321";
```

I tested it with this link

```
http://smsgateway.me/api/v3/messages/send?email=xxx&password=xxx&device=xxx&number[0]=123456789&number[1]=987654321&message=test
```

and that works.

**EDIT**
As per your comment.

I'm not familiar with InfoPath but based on [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa945227.aspx) you can add multiple numbers to the query like this:

```
XPathNavigator root = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator nodes = root.Select("/my:myFields/my:group1/my:myGroup/my:myNumber", NamespaceManager);
var i = 0;
while (nodes.MoveNext())
{
    parameters["number[" + i + "]"] = nodes.Current.Value;
    i++;
}
```

Be careful though, you might run in to problems when the URI becomes extremely long.

Comment: thanks. it is working. venerik is it possible to make these numbers varible? means if once I have 100 numbers to send sms and again i have 80 numbers to send sms

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean but every request is independent of other requests. So, sending the first 100 messages you can use number[0] through number[99] and sending the next 80 message you can use number[0] through number[79]. By the way: accepting the answer if much appreciated B-)

Comment: My Mistake that I am not able to clarify my self. Basically I am trying to create an infopath form. when clicked on button on form SMSs will be sent. Quantity of Mobile Numbers is not defined. It is not possible for me to tell whether there will be 100 Mobile Numbers or 80 Mobile Numbers or 1000 Mobile Numbers. So in filling form a person enters 100 Mobile Numbers, HOW IN THE CODE I CAN DEFINE THIS? Mobile Numbers will be manually entered in form.

Comment: I have Created a field myNumbers and entered mobile numbers, separated my commas. But SMSGATEWAY.ME is treating all numbers as one. What I am Doing wrong here?

Comment: As I said, I'm not familiar with InfoPath but I think you should configure a repeating table (myGroup) containing a field for a number (myNumber). The repeating table gives the user the opportunity to enter multiple numbers. In that case you can use my code to insert the numbers in the query string.

Comment: You Are Simply Great. Thanks For Help Bro. It is Working. Just a simple change in your code  /my:myFields/my:group1/my:myGroup/my:myNumber